# How do I filter incoming data from a socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am using a UDP socket program for one of my projects to read in incoming data from an EEG headset. I then use this data to control servo motors in a robotic arm. The code that I am using to create the socket and print out the data works fine.

```
import socket
import subprocess

UDP_IP = "169.254.110.133"
UDP_PORT = 50000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
        (data,addr) = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(data)
```

The data that is coming in is raw EEG data from the headset and it looks like this in the terminal:

```
SourceTime 31972

TargetCode 1

ResultCode 0

Feedback 1

PauseApplication 0

CursorPosX 717

CursorPosY 2047

CursorPosZ 2047
```

This data has 33 different sections each few milliseconds. The data always comes in the same order. For my code, I only need a few pieces of information from the data (TargetCode, ResultCode, and Feedback). How do I filter out these sections and use them in my code. Is there a way to look for TargetCode and copy the number? Or since TargetCode is always number 24 in the stream of 33 sections can I extract it that way?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. You can apply filters on Linux sockets (see below for other platform alternatives) using the python call:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, filter)
```

However we are talking about a compiled and parsed filter:

> The argument for SO_ATTACH_FILTER is a sock_fprog structure,
>             defined in :
>
> ```
>   struct sock_fprog {
>       unsigned short  len;
>       struct sock_filter *filter;
>   };
> ```
>
> The argument for SO_ATTACH_BPF is a file descriptor returned
>   by the bpf(2) system call and must refer to a program of type
>                 BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER.
>
> Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

Which is not something easy to build, especially on Python.

A few good options:

- use scapy’s `attach_filter(socket, filter, interface)` function (Linux & OSX), which uses tcpdump to parse the filter, then builds the compiler filter and apply it to your socket
- use scapy’s builtins sockets (install scapy, use `sock = conf.L2socket(filter="tcp")` for instance. That is cross-platform (even Windows). Google for more infos)

All you will have to then is pass a filter such as:

```
host 10.0.0.1
port 80
tcp port 80 and host 10.0.0.1
host 10.0.0.1 or host 10.0.0.2 or port 80 or port 443
```

￼
All filters are in BPF format (have a look on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter)

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

**Server**

```
import socket              

s = socket.socket()         
UDP_IP = "169.254.110.133"
UDP_PORT = 50000              
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))        

s.listen(5)                 
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   c.send('Connected to server.')
   c.close()
```

**Client**

```
import socket               
UDP_IP = "169.254.110.133"
UDP_PORT = 50000   
s = socket.socket()         
s.connect((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that doesn't exactly seem to fix my problem. The server side of the program is the EEG headset program which just asks me to put in the IP and port number to send the data to. On the client side I need a way to just extract a few bits of data from the incoming stream. Is there a way to use maybe a for loop for this? or some way to say if it sees the word TargetCode get the number after that?

Comment: So you just need to extract the targetcode from eeg? Is it a string?

Comment: If it is a string then the number extraction will be  >> int(outputData.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[1])

Comment: Did it help? @JustinK